# How to stop ZoneRefresh mixins in tapestry

Tags: mixins, tapestry, zone

I'm using the tapestry ZoneRefresh mixins to update zone periodically.

```
<t:zone t:id="zoneInf" t:mixins="zonerefresh" t:period="4" t:update="show"> 
        <t:if test="ready"> 
                success & How to stop refreshing
            <p:else>
                Loading...
            </p:else>
        </t:if>
</t:zone>
```

My question is: How to stop the refresh? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might have to write your own mixin. But it is very little code. Take a look at http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/ajax/periodicupdatemixin and http://tapestry5-jquery.com/mixins/docszonerefresh